# How Can I Fix a Hacked Wordpress Website?

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, virus-scanning

I have seen lots of critical errors on my WordPress website. I attached a screenshot below that shows some of these issues. Please look at this and provide some suggestions so that I can fix this problem.

Thank you so much.

[image: Wordfence Scan Results screenshot]

Comment: restore your latest clean backup.

Comment: by the way, in the screenshot you linked there are magic wand "REPAIR" icons. it looks like you already have some sort of security plugin installed, it should offer you some procedure to repair the WP installation

Answer (score 1):

Depends how badly broken your site has become.

What is it doing to make you think it's been hacked? Is it just the warnings in the Wordfence scan report?

Before going much further you should for sure grab a backup of your database, wp-config.php, and the contents of the directories wp-content/themes, wp-content/uploads, and wp-content/plugins. Might be a good idea to make a separate backup of the entire WordPress installation directory.

Since you can still access the administration panel, might as well change your password just to be safe. Are there multiple users for your WP installation?

What changes have been made if you click "Details" button in the Wordfence scan?

If you're sure changes to the wp-core files are due to a hack, you can try to repair them using Wordfence's repair feature--it'll restore them to their base WordPress version. But if significant differences are showing for dozens of core files, might be a good idea start over with a clean installation of WordPress.

You'll also want to track down what allowed these malicious changes to be made (has an unknown IP logged into your administration panel recently? Are you using a plugin with a known security issue?), or it'll just happen again.

Comment: last paragraph is very important, finding the underlying vulnerability and fixing it. wordpress can very easily become a security nightmare.